# Creating winforms executable dynamically C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I want to create an application, that will take out the text from textBox1, compile it, and save it as an executable. I never tried this before, but I would really like to get it working. **This is the code that I'm using in my "compiler" application:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;
using Microsoft.CSharp;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace Compiler
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CSharpCodeProvider codeProvider = new CSharpCodeProvider();
            ICodeCompiler icc = codeProvider.CreateCompiler();
            string Output = "out.exe";
            Button ButtonObject = (Button)sender;
            CompilerParameters parameters = new CompilerParameters();
            string[] references = { "System.dll","System.Windows.Forms.dll","System.Drawing.dll" };

            parameters.EmbeddedResources.AddRange(references);
            parameters.GenerateExecutable = true;
            parameters.OutputAssembly = Output;
            CompilerResults results = icc.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parameters, textBox1.Text);

            if (results.Errors.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (CompilerError CompErr in results.Errors)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(CompErr.ToString());
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //Successful Compile
                textBox1.ForeColor = Color.Blue;
                textBox1.Text = "Success!";
            }

        }
    }
}
```

**The textbox1 text, meaning the source that I am trying to compile is:**

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
System.Windows.Forms.Form f = new System.Windows.Forms.Form(); 
f.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

Basically, I am trying to generate an executable file dynamically, that will just show a Form. I've also tried, instead of making and showing a form to show a System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("testing");

In both cases I get this errors:

> Line number 5, Error Number: CS0234, 'The type or namespace name
>   'Windows' does not exist in the namespace 'System' (are you missing an
>   assembly reference?);
>
> Line number 5, Error Number: CS0234, 'The type or namespace name
>   'Windows' does not exist in the namespace 'System' (are you missing an
>   assembly reference?);

Comment: So what did you try to resolve these errors? Do you know how compilation in general, and references in specific work? What kind of answer do you expect?

Comment: I am expecting an answer to solve the problem, obviously. I don't know why I get this. I added the System.Windows.Forms.dll into it. If I use an easier source, just to make a console application, it works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are adding 3 files ("System.dll","System.Windows.Forms.dll","System.Drawing.dll") as embedded resources not as references. Add them to ReferencedAssemblies instead.

Comment: Hehe, thank you buddy. It works :) I will accept the answer in 8 minutes.